# How go generate a movie from Google Earth studio ESP file and images

Tags: render, google-earth-studio

How to create a movie from a `.esp` file (which is actually JSON) and a set of images that Google Earth Studio generates when you render?

The docs recommend Adobe products, but those are paid and I only need this once: https://earth.google.com/studio/docs/making-animations/rendering/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)

Like so:

`ffmpeg -f image2 -r 30 -i your_project%03d.png -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`

Where the `-r` flag is the Frame rate you chose, and the `-i` flag the name pattern of the jpges in the `footage` folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Blender which is free. It already has a plugin that allows you to import the jpg sequence rendered in Google Earth Studio with the JSON file so that you can edit your video and use the track points.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this question was about an older/outdated version of Earth Studio since, nowadays, you can simply choose to render as an `.mp4`.

Plus, there's even the option to render as a 360° spherical `.mp4`...  very cool when played on an Oculus Quest - as long as I avoid including sudden turns in the animation. (I literally almost barfed, which was simultaneously awful and awesome.)

[image: screamshot]

On the other hand, the question says "movie" (without a filetype) which is pretty vague, so I'll paste in some [messy] JavaScript that I slapped together to dynamically display a set of rendered `.jpeg` frames, automatically progressing through the frames -- but with an `<input type="range">` slider to also allow manual movement through the frames...

```css
<style>
  body{ font-family:sans-serif; 
    background:#000; color:#fff; 
    margin:0; 
    overflow:hidden; }

  #cont{ position:absolute;
    width:min(1000px,98vw);
    height:min(1000px,98vh);
    left:50%; top:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);}

  img{ max-width:100%; max-height:100%;
    position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);}

  #rgcont{ position:absolute; z-index:99;
    left:3%; right:3%; top:3%; 
    width:100vw; height:20px; 
    transform-origin:3% 3%; 
    transition:300ms;}

  input{ width:90%; left:50%;
    transform:translatex(-50%); 
    position:absolute;
    filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 5px #000)  
            drop-shadow(-3px -3px 5px #000); }

  @media(orientation:landscape){
    #rgcont{ width:100vh;
      transform:rotate(90deg) translatey(-50%); }
  }

  #info{ position:absolute; 
    right:5px; bottom:5px; 
    font-size:22px; }
</style>
```

## **[html](/questions/tagged/html) & [js](/questions/tagged/js)**

```html
<div id='cont'><img id='iimg' src=''></div>
<div id='rgcont'>
  <input type="range" id='rg' min='0' max='182' value='0' oninput="slid()">
</div>
<div id='info'></div>

<script>
  var imgs={}, loaded=0, 
      urls=[], auto=true, idx=0;

  for(var i=0;i<=182;i++){
    var n=i.toString().padStart(3,'0'),
    url="https://example.com/myframes_"+n+".jpeg"; 
    urls.push(url);
    imgs[i]=new Image(1000,1000);
    imgs[i].addEventListener('load',did1);
    imgs[i].src=url;
  }

  function did1(e){
    info.innerHTML=(100*((++loaded)/183)).toFixed()+'%';
     if(loaded==1){frame();}
  }
  function slid(){ 
    idx=parseInt(rg.value);
    auto=false;
   frame(idx); 
  }

  function frame(){
    iimg.src=urls[idx];
    if(auto){
      if((++idx)<=182){
        requestAnimationFrame(frame)
      }else{
        idx=182;
        auto=false;
      }
      rg.value=idx;
    }
  }
</script>
```

The hard-coded `182` is the total count of frames. Again, I'm not claiming this code works; just giving an idea.